# Fixing Path Manipulation error

Tags: java, validation, fortify

Fortify is giving Path Manipulation error on line where new File(path) comparison is made. I'm using Struts 2.

Can any one tell me how to fix this issue so that fortify won't give this error?

```
private boolean filePresent(String fileName) {
    if (fileName != null) {
        String path = getDirPath();
        if (path != null) {
            path = path.endsWith("/") ? path : path + "/";
            path = path + fileName;
            if (new File(path).exists()) {
                setFileName(fileName);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I need to see whether the file is present or not in our web server & hence I'm passing file name as an argument, getting the entire directory path from web.xml, appending it to file name & then composing the path & checking it against File object to see if it is present or not.

Answer (score 6):

You don't want the remote web user to see whether C:/Windows/System32 exists, or whether /etc/hosts exists, because that allows them to do forensic research on your server.

You probably didn't realize that your function allows them to do just that, by including an appropriate number of ".." sequences in the input string.

There are two ways to stop the problem:

1. Whitelist approach. Scrub all the characters in the input parameter and only allow "a" through "z" and perhaps "."  Throw an exception if the input falls outside of these bounds.

1a. Or, if you know the list of valid files is less than 20, just list them out and if the input doesn't make an exact match, throw an exception.

1. Blacklist approach. Check the input and throw an exception if it contains any sequence ".." or any forward slashes or backslashes.  This is GENERALLY not a defense in depth, but for your function as I read it right now, this would be OK.

Comment: Hi @Douglas, For our project, we are using blacklist as "(\\.\\.\\\\|\\\\|\\.\\./|/)" But I am not getting how it can be used as blacklist as any path will always have forward slashes or backslashes (sorry if the question is too basic considering I am not so good at regular expressions).

Comment: Hi Gaurav, this is not so much about regex but about your expected inputs. Note if getFilePath() returns "D:\App\files" and fileName = "foo.txt" then existence will be checked for D:\App\files\foo.txt. Are you expecting  "subdir\\foo.txt" instead? Will you correctly handle "subdir/foo.txt"? I cannot evaluate your regex question unless you provide the actual Java comparison expression.

Answer (score 0):

You can even use filter to do it like

in Filter

```
chain.doFilter(new RequestWrapper((HttpServletRequest) request), response);
```

in RequestWarper use something  like

```
if(value.contains("..\\"))
value = value.replace("..\\", "");
        if(value.contains("../"))
            value = value.replace("../", "");
        if(value.contains("./"))
            value = value.replace("./", "");
```