# How to avoid "Path Manipulation" error in Fortify?

Tags: fortify

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to fix ‘Path Manipulation’ issue from Fortify scan report for tthe following code sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732967/how-to-fix-path-manipulation-issue-from-fortify-scan-report-for-tthe-following)

Fortify is giving Path Manipulation error on line where `new FileWriter(psPath + psFileName + psExtension, false)`.

Can any one tell me how to fix this issue so that fortify won't give this error?

```
public void setWriter(String psPath, String psFileName, String psExtension)
        throws Exception {
    fwFileWriter = new FileWriter(psPath + psFileName + psExtension, false);
    bwFileWriter = new BufferedWriter(fwFileWriter);
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9745896/fixing-path-manipulation-error (similar Java question) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732967/how-to-fix-path-manipulation-issue-from-fortify-scan-report-for-tthe-following (this is C#, but it talks about the same principles)

Comment: I am getting Path Manipulation error whenever i used to write new File(path); How can i fix this?

Comment: See the links which provide two possible approaches (whitelist and blacklist).

Comment: Could you please provide sample code for whitelist approach and black list approch? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please help me on this, i am strugling from long time to fix Fortify fix. Even if i mention File file=new File(path) also showing fority error.

Comment: you can use blacklist as "(\\.\\.\\\\|\\\\|\\.\\./|/)"